# How to solve a "429: Too Many Requests" when running discord.py bot on repl.it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code (see below) was running fine, but then this error popped up and doesn't go away:

```py
"http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 209, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): "
```

I searched up the error, and I saw that people got it from running powerful programs on multiple servers, or people running the same code tons of times on a single one. But, I only run it on one server and it's very simple code.

Here's the code for reference (it's running in repl.it) (the os.getenv is to hide the bot's token):

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 7):

Other than avoiding the error, there's a way to get around it. If `discord.errors.HTTPException: 429` appears in the console on replit, just use the command `kill 1` in the shell. This command completely exits the script, and when you click run again it will run from a different IP Address, bypassing the Discord rate limit.

If the error happens regularly, this can be a hassle. An automatic solution is to have another file called 'restarter.py' with this code:

```
from time import sleep
from os import system
sleep(7)
system("python main.py")
```

Then in your main script:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

try:
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
except discord.errors.HTTPException:
    print("\n\n\nBLOCKED BY RATE LIMITS\nRESTARTING NOW\n\n\n")
    system("python restarter.py")
    system('kill 1')
```

Comment: For the `HTTPException`, you should check if it's a `429` before restarting. You don't want to have to restart the bot because of a `403` or `400`.

Answer (score 0):

Cohen's solution worked pretty decently for me. However, sometimes the bot got stuck in a loop of trying to start the bot over and over again and constantly crashing. This got solved only after the Cloudflare ban expired (1 hour). I really could not figure out why or what happens, but I found a solution.

I have a main.py file, that imports my bot.py file, where all my bot code is located. The runbot function is just bot.run(token).

```
import bot.bot as bot
from bot.keep_alive import keep_alive
import os
import discord

while __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    keep_alive()
    bot.runbot(os.environ['token'])
  except discord.errors.HTTPException as e:
    print(e)
    print("\n\n\nBLOCKED BY RATE LIMITS\nRESTARTING NOW\n\n\n")
    os.system('kill 1')
```

Instead of using the restarter.py file, I'm just using a while loop. This makes sure that everything is executed in the correct order.