# Traceback error while creating a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I was creating a basic python but and I keep getting this massive traceback error. It was working originally and then I switched up the code a little and got the error. I then tried commenting out what I had written but it still returns this error. What is wrong with it?

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import random
#import urllib.request
#import json

#api = os.environ['ApiKey']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
bot.videos = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmoKM4RunZQ',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTmjKpl2Jk0',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hY7m5jjJ9mM'
]


#@bot.command()
#async def search(ctx, input):
#  url = "https://imdb-api.com/en/API/SearchMovie/" + api + "/" + input;
#  req = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
#  data = json.loads(req)
#  await ctx.send(data)

@bot.command()  
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello " + ctx.author.display_name)


@bot.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(bot.videos))


@bot.command()
async def happy(ctx, *, item):
    await ctx.send("Awesome!")
    bot.happylist.append(item)
    print(bot.happylist)


@bot.command()
async def sad(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hope this makes you feel better!")
    await ctx.send(random.choice(bot.happylist))


@bot.command()
async def calc(ctx, x: float, fn: str, y: float):
    if fn == '+':
        await ctx.send(x + y)
    elif fn == '-':
        await ctx.send(x - y)
    elif fn == '*':
        await ctx.send(x * y)
    elif fn == '/':
        await ctx.send(x / y)
    else:
        await ctx.send("We only support 4 function operations")


password = os.environ['password']
bot.run(password)
```

and heres the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 61, in <module>
    bot.run(password)
  File "/home/runner/chatbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/chatbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/chatbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/runner/chatbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/runner/chatbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/chatbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://api.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 71643901ee3c139a &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-06-04 22:49:36 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">71643901ee3c139a</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 34.82.250.161</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'71643901ee3c139a',m:'Vy.Q.DAKTQGlwogr5_Zq6mJ.XI.4iEMA73ojP1S.n8M-1654382976-0-AUwTtcSmYDa4yGdhJdUqeOtnKFtpnDuMDaR+h2pVff2tMI6ULgld0SWSU/d3vveoniF166IdrBSWv4R1qWLTzPALqbQgIrH1GxeZO6jzkZivoKOZloO4F0XXm2YJPgu4aGtIoMuh32ckjKLWGOw05zQ=',s:[0xd87400444f,0xe085f22f77],}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Discord.Py, how to solve the error for TooManyRequests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/in-discord-py-how-to-solve-the-error-for-toomanyrequests)

Comment: See above. Are you running this on a shared host? If it gives you such a raw message (and not sending you ratelimit responses after you have logged in that the library can handle itself), you're definitely doing something **really** wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Replit. Replit uses shared resources, so your bot may get rated limit occasionally. For temporary method, you can type in `kill 1` in the Replit console to switch to another container and avoid the rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is replit's rate limit

To bypass this make a file named `restarter.py` and add the following code

```py
from time import sleep
from os import system
sleep(7)
system("python main.py")
```

and then edit your `bot.run(passowrd)` to

```py
try:
    bot.run(password)
except discord.errors.HTTPException:
    print("\n\n\nBLOCKED BY RATE LIMITS\nRESTARTING NOW\n\n\n")
    os.system("python restarter.py")
    os.system('kill 1')
```