# Failed to run discord bot 24/7

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot from replit, I have done the setup and added a few command. Everything was working fine but sometimes it gives the this error and shuts down.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 347, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('RealToken'))
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Moderator-bot-Help-required/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Moderator-bot-Help-required/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Moderator-bot-Help-required/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Moderator-bot-Help-required/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Moderator-bot-Help-required/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Moderator-bot-Help-required/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://api.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 7204d7bcafad813f &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-06-24 10:39:59 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">7204d7bcafad813f</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 34.70.239.3</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7204d7bcafad813f',m:'0Wr6FctHLZ54KeOLBruwAisfYFVMG.ryU7OaDPiTg5g-1656067199-0-ATWFwJVimUrXyWHYhlPg2KKWfl/k4QYZIjsHm8aRrmnI59KKtgK2RCw/IiQyFQ/isMNaI3DA5ivqDXVf9L9jDFMqx0MoDCBDRQ9XgrSzcZcceoJMYCPZqKnoruO7ODkggkiIFQeibhc3R4hxnNYYKY4=',s:[0x2c0bd5657f,0xfb46c3f524],}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

And after like 2-9 hours it runs automatically but today it is giving me this error for **11 hours** and is not starting at all. Is there a way to fix this or another way to keep discord bot 24/7 online from replit. Please help me.

This is my code in `keep_alive.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "I am alive bro!!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

And this is my code in `main.py`

```
#import stuff
import discord
import random
import os
import youtube_dl
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from replit import db
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


#variables
paint=[0xff0000 , 0x0000ff , 0x000000 , 0x00ffff , 0xffffff , 0xffd700 , 0x4b0082]
number=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
heads_tails = ['Heads', 'Tails']
prefix = ['-']
client = commands.Bot(prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

status = random.choice(['-help • Version 0.1.1'])
#when ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Ready to help you!")
  while True:
    statusType = random.randint(0, 1)
    if statusType == 0:
      statusNum = random.randint(0, 10)
      await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=f"{status}"))
    else:
      statusNum = random.randint(0, 10)
      await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="GameMaker on youtube"))
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    
#help command
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, cmd=""):
  if cmd == "toss":
    await ctx.channel.send("Toss is a command which can be used by anyone to flip a coin!")
  elif cmd == "randomnumber":
    await ctx.channel.send("Randomnumber is a command which can be used by anyone to get a random number between 1 and 50!")
  else:
    embedVar1 = discord.Embed(
        title="Help arrived!",
        description="Here is a list of commands for your help! To get info on a particular command use -help (commandname)",
        colour=(0xff0000))
    embedVar1.add_field(name="Bot Prefix", value="-", inline=False)
    embedVar1.add_field(name="Moderation Commands", value="help, say, mute/unmute, lockdown/unlock, warn/deletewarn/warnings", inline=True)
    embedVar1.add_field(name="Fun commands", value="toss, randomnumber", inline=True)
    embedVar1.set_thumbnail(
        url=
        "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/923531605660815373/974248483479494686/charizard-mega-charizard-y.gif"
    )
    print(f'help used by {ctx.author}')
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar1)

#mute command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  if member == ctx.author:
    muteerror = ("You can't mute yourself")
    await ctx.send(muteerror)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    embedVar2 = discord.Embed(
      title="User Muted",
      description=(f"Sucessfully muted {member}"),
      colour=(0xff0000))
    print(f'{ctx.author} muted {member}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar2)
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the 'staff' role")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid member")

#unmute command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  if member == ctx.author:
    unmuteerror = ("You can't mute yourself")
    await ctx.send(unmuteerror)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    embedVar2 = discord.Embed(
      title="User Unmuted",
      description=(f"Sucessfully unmuted {member}"),
      colour=(0xff0000))
    print(f'{ctx.author} has unmuted {member}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar2)
@mute.error
async def unmute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the 'staff' role")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid member")
      
#clear command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def clear(ctx , amount=5):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)

#lockdown command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,send_messages=False)
    embedVar3 = discord.Embed(
      title="Locked",
      description=(f'{ctx.channel.mention} ***has been locked.***'),
    colour=(0x0000ff))
    print(f"{ctx.author} has locked {ctx.channel}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar3)

#unlock command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=True)
    embedVar4 = discord.Embed(
      title="Unlocked",
      description=(f'{ctx.channel.mention} ***has been unlocked.***'),
    colour=(0x0000ff))
    print(f"{ctx.author} has unlocked {ctx.channel}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar4)

#randomnumber command
@client.command()
async def randomnumber(ctx):
        embedVar5 = discord.Embed(
            title="Random Number",
            description=(f'You got {random.choice(number)}'),
            colour=(0x0000ff))
        print(f'randomnumber used by {ctx.author}')
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar5)

#toss command
@client.command()
async def toss(ctx):
        embedVar6 = discord.Embed(
            title="Flipping the coin!",
            description=(f'You got {random.choice(heads_tails)}!'),
            colour=(0x4b0082))
        print(f'toss used by {ctx.author}')
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar6)

#say command
@client.command(name='say')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def audit(ctx, top=None ,msg=None):
    if msg and top is not None:
      embedVar7 = discord.Embed(
            title=(f'{top}'),
            description=(f'{msg}'),
            colour=(0x0000ff))
      print(f'say used by {ctx.author}')
      await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar7)
      await ctx.message.delete()

#warn command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warn(ctx, user: discord.Member,*,reason=""):
  if reason == "":
    embedVar8 = discord.Embed(
      title=(f"Error"),
      desription=("Please specify a reason!"),
      colour=(0xff0000))
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar8)

  else:
    embedVar9 = discord.Embed(
      title=('**User Warned**'),
      description=(f'{user} has been warned because: {reason}'),
      colour=(0xff0000))
    user_id = str(user.id)

    if user_id in db:
      db[user_id].append(reason)
    else:
      db[user_id] = [reason]
    print(f"{ctx.author} has warned {user}")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar9)
    
#warningslist command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warnings(ctx, user: discord.Member):
  warnlist = db[str(user.id)]
  embedVar10 = discord.Embed(
    title=(f"Warnings of {user.name}"),
    description= "\n".join(f"{i}) {r}" for i, r in enumerate(warnlist, 1)),
    colour=(0xff0000))
  print(f"{ctx.author} has seen the warns of {user}")
  await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar10)

#deletewarn command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def deletewarn(ctx, user: discord.Member,*, n: int):
    embedVar11 = discord.Embed(
     title=(f"Removed warn of {user.name}"),
     description=(f"Warn {n} of {user} removed!"),
     colour=(0xff0000))
    if str(user.id) in db:
      db[str(user.id)].pop(n-1)
    print(f"{ctx.author} has deleted the warn of {user}")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar11)

#addrole command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addrole(ctx, member: discord.Member,*, rolee):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=(rolee))
    await member.add_roles(role)
    embedVar12 = discord.Embed(
      title="Role added",
      description=(f"Sucessfully added {rolee} role to {member}"),
      colour=(0xff0000))
    print(f'{ctx.author} has added {rolee} to {member}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar12)
@mute.error
async def addrole_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the 'staff' role")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid member")

#removerole command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def removerole(ctx, member: discord.Member,*,rolee):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=(rolee))
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    embedVar13 = discord.Embed(
      title="Role removed",
      description=(f"Sucessfully removed {rolee} role from {member}"),
      colour=(0xff0000))
    print(f'{ctx.author} has removed {rolee} to {member}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar13)
@mute.error
async def removerole_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the 'staff' role")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid member")

#verify command
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
  if ctx.channel.id == 988804866321293342:
    embedVar14 = discord.Embed(title="Verified",description=f"{ctx.author.mention} you have been verified!", colour=(0xff0000))
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar14)

#kick command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="Reason Not specified!"):
  if member != ctx.author:
    embedVar15 = discord.Embed(title="Kicked", description=(f'{member.mention} has been kick for {reason}'), colour=(0xff0000))
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar15)
    await member.send(f'You have been kicked in {ctx.guild} for {reason}!')

#ban command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="Reason Not specified!"):
  if member != ctx.author:
    embedVar16 = discord.Embed(title="Banned", description=(f'{member.mention} has been banned for {reason}'), colour=(0xff0000))
    await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar16)
    await member.send(f'You have been banned in {ctx.guild} for {reason}! If you wish to appeal to be unbanned, then appeal here https://forms.gle/qBNWZTMuF3VkMcGs9')
    
#24/7 active
keep_alive()
#run
client.run(os.getenv('RealToken'))
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have edited it. Please see if its ok or not. @MariusROBERT

Comment: It's not ok, you gotta give the .py that you are running for your bot;

Comment: Is it good now? I gave my whole code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Discord.Py, how to solve the error for TooManyRequests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/in-discord-py-how-to-solve-the-error-for-toomanyrequests)

Comment: No, it doesnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what should be done.

**1) Create a file called restarter.py**

Add this code to it

```py
from time import sleep
from os import system
sleep(7)
system("python main.py")
```

**2) Go to main.py and change this code**

From

```py
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('RealToken'))
```

To

```
keep_alive()
try:
  client.run(os.getenv('RealToken'))
except discord.errors.HTTPException:
    print("\n\n\nBLOCKED BY RATE LIMITS\nRESTARTING NOW\n\n\n")
    os.system("python restarter.py")
    os.system('kill 1')
```

This worked for me and it should work for others also. Thanks to someone for telling me this.