# discord bot adding roles

Tags: discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot in python and I want to figure out how to give a role to myself, without notifying anything besides a conformation in the console.

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == '‎':
      # i want to give myself a role right here
      print('adding admin role to', message.author)
    print(message.author,message.content)



try:
    client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
except discord.HTTPException as e:
    if e.status == 429:
        print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
        print("Get help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/in-discord-py-how-to-solve-the-error-for-toomanyrequests")
    else:
        raise e
```

Comment: Please be a bit more clear in what you intend to achieve. By expecting a confirmation is a considered a notification in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Get the role, using either [`utils.get` on its name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get):

```py
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=some_name)
```

or its [ID](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role):

```py
role = message.guild.get_role(12345)
```

Then you can [add the role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles) to the member.

```py
await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

(Also, please don't randomly give people admin if they send a specific message. That's going to end up being abused in some way.)