# Temporarily banned from discord.com when I run my bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

When I run my discord bot on repl.it I get this error:

```
File "/home/runner/Corion/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Corion/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Corion/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/runner/Corion/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/runner/Corion/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/Corion/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 73990c4ecab3f1c2 &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-08-12 11:59:59 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">73990c4ecab3f1c2</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.148.74.116</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script>(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'73990c4ecab3f1c2',m:'ZZZhJFNVNHYLickxh1XYrlNzM.1fho4dblARAti1uyA-1660305599-0-AbknsK/Rrl6GeFpqkaRI+AZfU3TBHEC9ykGXUFvIYTmWYdKAyQCLcyPt5UCO82+XIFRijz7IkNQC/8evdUtokX+Bq7HvuUW3oBtB7KTAwyq2Pi/8+agYSbDzVxB2ZFaP3dQ02HFhruUe4PrFz2Y6+Uo=',s:[0x2b5eeb00dc,0xbad3d42444],}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

It was working perfectly fine, I changed a string and now I get this error. I changed it then back to normal but I'm still getting this error. I've been working on this project for about a week.
I tried typing `kill 1` in shell multiple times but I still get the error. What is going on?

Comment: *"Too Many Requests"*: that should give you a clue?

Comment: "I tried typing `kill 1` in shell multiple times but I still get the error" - why would you expect typing `kill 1` into your shell to do anything about a Discord ban?

Comment: @trincot No I don't have a clue what is happening still. My bot is not a spam bot or anything like that.

Comment: @user2357112 Because kill 1 changes the ip. I tried it in the past and it worked. Now it doesn't.

Comment: Oh so you are trying to circumvent the request limit by regularly changing the IP? They must be happy with that.

Comment: @trincot What do you mean by that? I've seen many answers to the same problem where `kill 1` works, so I tried it too.

Comment: It's DDOS protection, it means you're sending too many requests too quickly. Changing your local IP won't make Cloudflare forget about you. Maybe if you could post your code as well, we could help you. If replit runs your code on their servers, it might be that replit has a lot of discord bots already, and Cloudflare is incorrectly identifying that as a ton of requests from the same place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Discord.Py, how to solve the error for TooManyRequests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/in-discord-py-how-to-solve-the-error-for-toomanyrequests)

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP sending too many requests. This is because the code is hosted on repl.it, where programs share the same IP which leads to rate limits simply from running the bot.

Comment: Instead use Heroku for your Discord bots. Not replit!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a shared IP? I have encountered this error before on services like Replit. It’s an error 429 (too many requests), so it’s likely just too many people using it causing replit’s servers to block it. Just wait a bit (maybe try another host if it still doesn’t work), and it should fix itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into a similar problem. A similar post on repl.it's forums gave me this chunk at the end of the program that did the trick. The answer varies based on how you have the code set up but it should apply to whatever method you're using.

```
try:
    asyncio.run(main()) #or whatever your "run" command is

except:
    os.system("kill 1")
```

Comment: `kill 1` kills the `init` process, the father of all process. And crashes surely the system. Which then rebooots and probably, if the system uses DHCP, that change the IP, indeed. But that is surely a strange and brutal way to solve problems. Plus most modern unix simply ignore "kill 1", in which case the command does nothing at all.