# Hosting discord.py bot on replit using flask and uptime robot issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have been using replit and flask (keep_alive) to host my bot and using uptime robot to keep it alive but every so often the bot stops running and in the console I get this traceback

```
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "/home/runner/Zafkiel-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Zafkiel-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Zafkiel-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Zafkiel-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Zafkiel-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/Zafkiel-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 680, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 742ff08a5f9ead43 &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-08-30 19:30:12 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">742ff08a5f9ead43</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.73.18.236</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script>(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'742ff08a5f9ead43',m:'8ku8rol7JNuCQEt3nS5tWIkq0jJYWXIabFXqD.0Imrc-1661887812-0-AaAmc004iIy4aVAKUpeWKz5Ypix9+QCnn1r5bTcZNk5MvjhzVQB1q9VcYnJNh6skcC8jTWnEdTqK28zNoMFKUX0IEFtEYTHL1yy8XXzpVAx60q9NNgkjyApOO9K9hj5C3K0u5B/3vOQZefEnlWObiF0=',s:[0xcb54de86e4,0x3d3dfb92f9],}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

It has been bugging me and I have to keep killing the console and re-running the bot for it to come back just for it to go through the same cycle again. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: I did a bit of digging and found out the bot is being rate limited but this bot doesn't have much code since it's just a welcome bot to send an embed whenever a member joins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a "429: Too Many Requests" when running discord.py bot on repl.it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/how-to-solve-a-429-too-many-requests-when-running-discord-py-bot-on-repl-it)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that UptimeRobot.com no longer supports replit monitoring.
This was made clear by an e-mail that was sent to all register accounts a few months back: [image]

You can also see it for yourself when you try to create a new replit monitor on UptimeRobot.com:
[image]

I would suggest that you chose a different hosting service for your discord bot.

Answer (score -1):

`Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access`

As stated in the error, the IP was restricted by cloudflare. There's a change that previously someone was using replit's IP for malicious purposes and thus whatever ip got banned

You can try going to the shell and typing `kill 1` as it could cause your application to be hosted on a different IP once restarted. See: https://ask.replit.com/t/how-can-i-reset-repl-ip/1235